# Why does SVN take so much space?

Tags: svn

I am working on a large sized project that is about 1020 MB in size. This is because, apart from the code, we have other resources, like graphics, XML configurations, etc. in the version control.

The size of the .svn-base files is about 998 MB, making the total checkout size about 2 GB. By my understanding .svn-base is meta information and its size shouldn't be that much.

Why does SVN need so much space?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So that `svn revert` doesn't need to contact the server.

SVN actually stores another copy of the file locally. That's why the `.svn` dirs sum up to be almost as the project code base itself.

Comment: So the previous version of the file is stored in its entirety?

Comment: @DietrichEpp But shouldn't it be saving the diff of the two files which would be substantially less in size?

Comment: @KshitizSharma: How would it know what the diff is?  At first, the diff is going to be zero.  SVN would have to somehow intercept your changes in order to record the diff.

Comment: @KshitizSharma How that? How should it actually compute that diff, if it hasn't got the original as a starting point? Note that there is not way to track modifications, since you can modify files inside a checkout in millions of ways.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, arkascha So would using GIT mean a less painful checkout process? What would be the size of checkout?

Comment: @KshitizSharma: Git would have even larger repositories, because it needs to locally store not just the previous version of everything, but the entire history.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: Git does the same thing.  You get a "working copy" that you can change, and Git stores a pristine copy so you can revert, compute a diff, etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's incorrect.  You can do shallow checkouts with Git, and Git also compresses the pristine copy.  `git clone --depth 1`

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Uh... huh? How does the fact that Git compresses the copy run contrary to what I said? A long history makes your repo bigger, simple as that... compression is irrelevant to that point...

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Regarding shallow copies: I haven't tried them, but AFAIK they aren't as functional as a normal copy like in SVN: [*"A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it)."*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html)

Comment: Is there no way to apply compression to SVN? Compressed version of our code is about 600MB. When checking out over the internet 1400MB makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: If you're on Windows, try taking advantage of NTFS's compression maybe? Aside from that I'm not sure...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sigh.  Let's try not to get into a VCS war.  We are not trying to fight Git versus SVN here, we are trying to provide information relevant to the question.  The reason compression is relevant is because it reduces the size of the working copy, and you said that "Git would have even larger repositories", where this is not always true, because Git compresses the repository.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I'm not trying to get into a war at all... I don't know why you got that impression. I like (and dislike) features from both Git and SVN, so I'm not advocating either here. Maybe what I said was ambiguous, but I didn't mean to imply Git *always* has a larger repo, I just meant to say that if you have a substantial history, then Git will have a larger repo as a general rule. Obviously, the exact numbers are dependent on the exact repo.

Comment: @Mehrdad NTFS compression? How is file system compression going to help me reduce the network transfer? I was wondering if there is a server setting that would compress the connection between SVN server and the client. Kind of like HTTP gzip compression that you have in httpd.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: Did you mention network transfer somewhere? I just thought you were running out of disk space...

Comment: @Mehrdad Disk space is no problem. Neither is checkout on the office intranet. But I'm trying to work from home over the internet.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: My bad, I just noticed you did mention it when you said "*When checking out over the internet 1400MB makes a lot of difference*"... I missed the "over internet" part, sorry.

Comment: @Mehrdad No problem. I'll post a separate question for SVN network compression. I think this one is answered.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks for sharing all that info.

Answer (score 20):

If there are many updates to your working copy, it might grow in size, even more than the checked out contents might suggest. Running `svn cleanup` will free this space again.

Comment: I reclaimed 6GB from a very old but very active local repository using this! :) Well worth knowing.

Comment: I'm using eclipse plugin, how can I do svn clean up? I have about 500 MB for a very small project after less than 24h of work.

Answer (score 0):

For binary data, SVN stores the entire copy on every new revision, not deltas. Thus - you get big repositories over time. `.svn-base` stores the pristine state of the working copy - if you have a big working copy, you have the same size of pristine-data.

Comment: svn stores deltas for text and binary data. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.forcvs.binary-and-trans : "Subversion, [...] expresses differences between files using a binary differencing algorithm, regardless of whether they contain textual or binary data.

Comment: @PeterParker - it's book and theory, I tried repository and practice. You can create repo with *some binary data-file*, commit some revisions with small changes and measure repo-size after it - it will be `~SIZE*N_COMMITS`, not `SIZE+N*SMALLDELTA`

Comment: No, I tried it myself. The only problem is with compressed data, like docx, jar or stuff, but if you have a .ppt(for example) and remove some slides and commit the commit will be not the size of the whole ppt.

Comment: @PeterParker - I have my [own project](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/show/customlocations-greylink) with mixed data (a lot of small files, *.txt + *.bmp). Unversioned tree - 3 MB, size of the whole project: `"Disk Space Usage: 107 MB of 2 GB"`

Comment: The problem in your repository is your unbalanced directory tree with 2000 small files in a single dir. So SVN needs to write for each (small) change to rewrite all entries in the same directory. this adds ab to about 100 kb in your case per revision. See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/subversion-design.html#server.fs.struct.bubble-up for further details