# Can I cause my .svn directories to take less space?

Tags: svn, space

I have half a dozen SVN repos on a server with plenty of space and bandwidth.

I therefore have half a dozen directories on my laptop with working copies, in which the .svn tree occupies the same or more space than the working copy does. I can see from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657359/why-does-svn-take-so-much-space) that SVN keeps the entire working copies in duplicate locally, so that revert doesn't need to contact the server.

Very kind of it. But disk space is more important on my laptop than the ability to revert quickly. Is there a configuration option which makes SVN **not** store a copy of the files locally?

These files are all my personal development and the repo is not shared; I also use them from other, bigger machines where disk space is not at a premium like it is on the laptop (yes, I know, get a new laptop...not an option right now)